# Multiple jqModal Windows - onLoad and onClick on the same page. How?

Tags: jqmodal

I am using jquery jqModal script for popup windows.

I have one html page with two jqModal windows.  I would like one to load when the page opens, and another one opens separately via onClick.

My script is not working.  The onLoad works (#success), but the onClick (#dialog) opens both up at the same time.

Here is my current script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

$('#dialog').jqm(); 

$('#success').jqm().jqmShow({});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the updated code u can try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dialog').jqm( {trigger:'#dialog'} ); 
    // $('#dialog').jqmAddTrigger('#dialog'); 
    $('#success').jqm().jqmShow({});
});
```

Let me know if its working for you
Here you need to add trigger when the modal window will open up

Answer (score 0):

The code you presented works without problems for me. Here is the complete snippet I used:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

           $(document).ready(function() {
           $('#dialog').jqm();     
           $('#success').jqm().jqmShow({});
       });


function showModal() {
        $('#dialog').jqmShow({});            
    }
</script>

<div id="dialog" class="jqmWindow">test</div>
<div id="success" class="jqmWindow">test</div>
<input type="button" value="Show Modal" onclick="showModal()"/>
```

Comment: just a comment here: I used jquery 1.4.2 - not sure if it matters or not